# Xpath query with appended nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm trying to add and search an element to a xml document. XPath returned "null" when i do the search for the recent added node.

Here's my document

```
    <root>
    </root>
```

That's my code

```
    File xmlFile = new File("C:\\caeycae.xml");
    String uri = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
    Element nodo = doc.createElementNS(uri, "e");
    nodo.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "a");

    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(nodo);
    Element testElement = (Element) getNode("root/e[@id='a']", doc);
    System.out.println("node:" + testElement);
    System.out.println("xml:" + doc.getDocumentElement());
```

The console output is:

```
    node: null
    xml: <root>
    <e id="a"/>
    </root>
```

Is there a way to notify Xpath that document has been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the new element in the SVG namespace but when you searched for it you looked for the element name "e" in no namespace.

(It's a bit questionable what should happen here anyway. XPath is defined on the XDM data model, not on DOM. The XDM model requires that when an element is in a particular namespace, it must have an in-scope namespace declaration for that namespace. With DOM it's possible to create trees that don't satisfy that constraint, and no-one has a definitive answer as to how XPath should behave when it meets such a tree.)